# how to compare string from .txt file with workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files, workspace

I'm having a .txt file like this:

```
structure
a = title
c1 = A.B.C
endstructure
```

I want to read this to matlab and then check if in my workspace already exists a structure named A.B.C. if so, then I want to save data from this structure to variable c1.
I have problem with proper parsing the line c1 = A.B.C and then comparing it with workspace. 
any help appreciated.

- - - - - - - explanation - - - - - -
              in my workspace there is a structure A.B.C. = [0 1 2 3 5 8]
              in my txt file I write c1 = A.B.C, and that is the name. I want in my program to check if this name matches some already existing data with this name in the workspace. if so, assign this data to a variable c1 and leave c1 in the workspace.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your data and its structure.  Perhaps post a toy example of what's contained in your `c1` and `A.B.C` elements?

Comment: try matalb's eval() , exist()

Comment: I have problem with parsing this structure. I don't know how to apply a proper regexp expression so that I obtain data convenient to work on. what I get is a structure of 2 cells 1 by 2: 'a' with 'title' (which is a string) and 'c1' with 'A.B.C' (which is a string to be matched with the name of workspace variable, if exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if your variable already exists in the Matlab workspace, you can use matlab [exist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html) function. It would be a little awkward in your situation though as you can only check to see if variable 'A' exists. You could then nest it further and see if the variable has the specified field. It could look like this:

```
if( exist('A','var') && isfield(A,'B') && isfield(A.B,'C') )
     %do something
end
```

Comment: thanks this is a good idea. But if I want to have c1, c2 c3 ... unspecified number of c's, each of them has a different name, and should be checked for matching with a different name from workspace. With your code I think I cannot make a loop of that. is there any other solution?

Comment: Whew, the only way I would know of at that point is by using eval(). While the exist function can take strings which you could dynamically generate, isfield() takes a structure, not just a var name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`evalin`](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/techdoc/ref/evalin.html) with the syntax `evalin('base',expression,catch_expr)` with expression the right side of your '=' sign.
It's not really efficient but it avoid you to have to parse the structure name. In `catch_expr` you can set a flag telling not to do the assignment.

Just use `assignin` after that to assign the value in 'c1'. 'c1' is a here string so it's easy to put it in a loop with different names.

Comment: but without pasing how can I actually assume and use c1 as a string? it is in .txt file so it's just a whole file of lines. I can parse it to become lines, with **textscan**. Then I have to separate c1 and A.B.C into separate cells. But my problem is I cannot do it, to make A.B.C a string. is it possible without parsing? if so please post some hint or example. thanks!

Comment: You will have to parse but it will be simpler. You should have a look at the documentation of regexp in Matlab especially the option 'tokens'.